# Finding the nodes with exactly similar inputs from other nodes in Networkx

Tags: python, graph, networkx

What is a fast way to find the groups of nodes that have the exactly same input edges from the exactly same nodes in Networkx?

For example if the graph is

```
1->2
1->3
1->4
3->4
```

then only nodes 2 and 3 are similar.
And the result would be

```
[[2, 3]]
```

Comment: What's your question?  There's no question here, or any real information.  WHen you say "'group nodes", which. nodes do you mean?  How are you defining your graph, and what does  it look like?  There's not enough information here for you to expect to get a useful answer.

Comment: @CryptoFool I have provided an example of a graph that I believe makes what I am looking for obvious. Also, corrected the question to actually have the question mark which you were looking for.

Comment: @Alireza What makes nodes 2 and 3 similar?  Node 1 is connected to nodes 2, 3, and 4, and node 3 is also connected to node 4.  Are 2 and 3 similar because they only have a single directed edge coming from node 1?  So if we were to add an edge `1->5`, then the result should be `[2, 3, 5]`.  Then if `5->3` is added, then the result becomes `[2, 5]`.  Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @Andrew That is exactly true. Two nodes are similar if they are "feeded" by the same nodes. (i.e. have in-edges from similar nodes)

Comment: @Alireza For what it's worth, there are a few confusing things about your post. We can't take your question literally because 2 and 3 cannot have "exactly the same input edges"; by definition, an input edge to 2 is distinct edge from an input edge to 3. That is, 1->2 and 1->3, even though they edges "from exactly the same nodes", are not "exactly the same edges".

Comment: It also wasn't clear you were considering a graph in the usual sense (i.e. an undirected graph) or a directed graph (AKA digraph); the only hints we had that you were considering a directed graph (which you apparently were) were your use of the phrase "input edges" (which is not standard terminology) and your use of the `->` symbol in your example, which for all we know could have merely been an artistic choice

Answer (score 2):

It seems as though what you're looking for is this. Given a **directed graph**, you're looking for groups of nodes such that two nodes u,v are in the same group whenever the set of nodes w for which w->u is an edge is the same as the set of nodes w for which w->v is an edge.

To put it another way, you're looking for groups of nodes such that for any u,v in the same group, the adjacency lists of u and v within the reversed graph are the same.

If I have interpreted your question correctly, then you should find the following script to be useful.

```
import networkx as nx
from collections import defaultdict

edges = [[1,2],[1,3],[1,4],[3,4]]
G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_edges_from(edges)

source_list = defaultdict(list)
for n,d in G.reverse().adjacency():
    source_list[tuple(sorted(d))].append(n)
groups = list(source_list.values())

print(groups)                           # [[1], [2, 3], [4]]
print([g for g in groups if len(g)>1])  # [[2, 3]]
```